# How to control the temperature of heating element

Tags: sensor, temperature, thermal, thermistor, rtd

I am developing a heating application where temperature need to be constant. I am planning to set the temperature @ 200 degree C. when my sensor find the temperature exceeding the set temperature how can i reduce the temperature of the heating element. I currently plan to cut the supply to heating element but is there any other method which i can reduce the temperature.

Comment: Can you regulate the power of the heating element?

Comment: What kind of heating element is this and how do you control it? A lot of them are fine with bang bang pwming.

Comment: I am hopping to regulate the power of heating element with a relay switch...the element I use is heat seal machine heating element. It's an ceramic type heater element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Practically you have two main choices involving i) on/off control; ii) average control.

i) Hysteretic control turns the heater on at a lower limit and turns it off at an upper limit. (i.e. on/off).

ii) Drive the heater with a fast switching PWM signal (via Switches and a switch-driver) so that the average value of the temperature is your desired setpoint value. This usually involves feedback and a controller such as a PID.

Comment: Does power off and on bring down the life of the Heating element ...?

Comment: Most heating wires have a positive tempco so they draw more current when cold so current surges may (in theory) reduce lifetime. In your case the element should stay at a fairly constant temperature so On/Off pulsing shouldn't be a problem.